# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars (for loop)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to code an analytical solution to a dam break in a rectangular channel. The idea is to have water on one side of the dam at 4m and no water on the downstream side of the dam, then to have the dam removed and see how the water evolves over time. I have the following code but im having issues with the "for i in range (x):" line. I will paste my code and the error i get. Can anyone explain why i get this error and any possible solutions? Thank you

```
    __author__="A.H"
__date__ ="$04-Aug-2014 13:46:59$"

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math 
import sys
from math import sqrt  
import decimal

nx, ny = (69,69)
x5 = np.linspace(0,20.1,nx)
y5 = np.linspace(0,20.1,ny)
xv,yv = np.meshgrid(x5,y5)
x = np.arange(0,20.3956,0.2956)
y = np.arange(0,20.3956,0.2956)
t59=np.arange (1,4761,1)


h0=4.0
g=9.81
t=1
xa=10.5-(t*math.sqrt(g*h0))
xb=10.5+(2*t*math.sqrt(g*h0))


h=np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(x):
   if x[i]<=xa:
      h=h0
   elif xa<=x[i]<=xb:
      h=(4.0/(9.0*g))*(((math.sqrt(g*h0))-(x[i]/(2.0*t)))**2.0)
   else:
      h=0

f = open(r'C:\opentelemac\bluetang\examples\telemac2d\dambreak\D1.i3s', 'r')
while True:
   line = f.readline()
   if line[0] not in [':','#']: break
ran = int(line.split()[0])
length = np.zeros(ran)
wse =  np.zeros(ran)
for i in range (ran):
   fields = f.readline().split()
   length[i] = float(fields[0])
   wse[i] = float(fields[2])
   all =[length[i],wse[i]]


plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(length,h)
plt.plot(length,wse)
plt.legend(['Analytical solution','Model'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

When i run this code i get the error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Work\NetBeansProjects\Ritter_test_2\src\ritter_test_2.py", line 29, in 
    for i in range(x):
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The second half of the code when i read the text file in works fine. I believe its just the for loop and if statements that have issues but i may be wrong. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `for i in range(x)` makes no sense - `x` is an array. Did you mean `range(len(x))`?

Comment: for i in range(x): x is an array. I think you meant for i in range(len(x))

Comment: The other possibility is to loop over `x` directly i.e. `for x_item in x`

Comment: Ah ok, yeah thats fixed that. However when i then try to print the length of h to check ive got the right amount of values in my array i get a new error. 

    print len(h)
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()

Any ideas why it only gives me onevalue for h?

Comment: You are initializing `h` to be an array of zeros the same length as `x`, but then you are assigning a scalar value to `h` in the `for` loop. Do you mean for `h` to be a scalar or a vector? Perhaps you meant to assign to elements of `h` in your `for` loop (e.g. `h[i] = ...`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others have pointed out that you most probably meant `range(len(x))`.

You can do it more simply by just iterating over the items in the array `x`:

```
for value in x:
    if value <= xa:
        h = h0
    elif xa <= value <= xb:
        h = (4.0/(9.0*g))*(((math.sqrt(g*h0))-(value/(2.0*t)))**2.0)
    else:
        h = 0
```

There's also a small issue with the condition in the `elif` - here `xa` can not be equal to `value` because if it was it would have already satisfied the previous condition in the `if value <= xa`. Just thought I'd point it out in case it's actually important.